# jQuery posting a serialized form to PHP

Tags: jquery, serialization, post

All,
I'm trying to post a form using jQuery and serializing the form. I have the following code to try and do that:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('#event_form').submit(function() {
    jQuery.post("test.php", $(this).serialize(),
        function(data) {
            alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
        });
});
});
```

Did I do something wrong with this because it doesn't get to the function that returns the data? If I comment out the complete jQuery.post stuff and replace it with an alert the alert is fired so I know it's something with how I wrote the .post function. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use the ID of the form instead of `this` as there may be a scope issue here. Alternatively you could create a variable for the data before the post function:

**Method 1:**

```
jQuery.post("test.php", $("#id_of_form").serialize();,
    function(data) {
        alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
    });
});
```

**Method 2:**

```
var formData = $(this).serialize();

jQuery.post("test.php", formData,
    function(data) {
        alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
    });
});
```